# Is there a way I can pass a variable in PHP on buttonclick?

Tags: php, html, button

I'm having a problem with passing a variable to a PHP function. So what I'm doing in html or actually PHP but I make a part of my HTML code with PHP is this:

```
<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">
    <textarea name=\"textarea\" rows=\"8\" cols=\"40\"></textarea>
    <button type=\"button\" class=\"button\" name=\"enterText\" value=\"".$row['Wagon_ID']."\">
        Enter
    </button>
</form>
```

Now this takes place in a while loop as long as there are more Wagon_ID's in the row array. 
What I want to do concretely is call a function on this button click but I must be able to pass along the Wagon_ID.
I can do this easily by using the `<input type="submit"...`and make the value the Wagon_ID but my problem with this is because the value is the Wagon_ID, that the text on the button will also become the Wagon_ID and the text needs to remain enter.
So what I tried is using the button type and setting the value to the Wagon_ID, but now the PHP function isn't even called.
Does anyone know a trick so I can use this type of button, or to maintain my "Enter" text on the type of button I previously used ?
Thanks in advance!

This is how I call the buttonclick in PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['enterText'])) 
    {
        $text= $_POST['textarea'];
        $wagon=$_POST['enterText'];
        mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'], "INSERT INTO description (Wagon_ID, textdescription) VALUES ('$wagon','$text')");
    }
```

Comment: `type="button"` gets you a “click button”. If you want to use this button to _submit_ the form, and transmit its value at the same time - then you want `type="submit"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key part of your question is here:

> I can do this easily by using the `<input type="submit` "...and make the
>   value the Wagon_ID but my problem with this is because the value is
>   the Wagon_ID, that the text on the button will also become the
>   Wagon_ID and the text needs to remain enter.

This situation is what hidden fields are for. Don't wrap actual form data in a UI element like a button. Try it like this:

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="textarea" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="wagonID" value="'.$row['Wagon_ID'].'"/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="enterText" value="Enter text" />
</form>';
```

And in the PHP change

```
$wagon=$_POST['enterText'];
```

to

```
$wagon = $_POST['wagonID'];
```

Documentation on hidden fields: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden

---

P.S. As you can see, you can get rid of all the messy escaping of double-quotes by echoing the string from PHP inside single quotes, and it's much more readable and less error-prone.

---

P.P.S.

**Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: Works like a charm, also thanks for pointing out I can get rid of all the backslashes! Also thank you for for pointing out the major security flaw I will def make sure it's fixed. Thank You !!